# Given the equation $A(qr-p)=B(pr+q)$, when can $A=pr+q$ and $B=qr-p$ be true?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

The following equations are known:
Given Equations
\begin{align}
A^2+B^2&=C^2\\
Ap+Bq&=Cr\\
p^2+q^2&=r^2+1\\
A&\neq B\\
Aq-Bp&=C
\end{align}
$A(qr-p)=B(pr+q)$ comes from the equations given above.

For this, I tried constructing a proof involving the prime factorization of $A(qr-p)$ and $B(pr+q)$ (which are just equal) and showed that since $A$ is not equal to $B$, then $A$ is equal to $pr+q$ and vice versa. However, I realized that I can make a lot of counterexamples for this (like $6 \cdot 4=8 \cdot 3$).

I really appreciate any form of hints or help that you could give. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi Jesse. I've typed up your image in MathJax so you can see how to format on the site. Just press the edit link to see the changes I've made. Hope this is ok.

Comment: @DanielBuck Noted. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr.Seiji Tomita has given parametric solution to the simultaneous equations shown below which was posted by "OP"
The link to his web site is article # 284 & his web address is given below:

www.maroon.dti.ne.jp

And select "Computational number Theory"

$\begin{align}
A^2+B^2&=C^2\\
Ap+Bq&=Cr\\
p^2+q^2&=r^2+1\\
A&\neq B\\
Bp-Aq&=C
\end{align}$

So, the answer is yes to the query by "OP" 
And $A=(pr-q)$  & $B=(qr+p)$

But "OP" equation has a typo & required a sign change

Parametric solution given by Seiji Tomita gives another numerical solution to the above system of equations:

$(A,B,C)=((2n),(2n^2+2n),(2n^2+2n+1))$

$(p,q,r) =((2n),(2n^2-1),(2n^2))$

So, for $n=3$ we get:  $(A,B,C)=(7,24,25)$  & $(p,q,r)=(6,17,18)$

Comment: interesting your explanation about the whole set (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$\begin{align}
A^2+B^2&=C^2\\
Ap+Bq&=Cr\\
p^2+q^2&=r^2+1\\
A&\neq B\\
Bp-Aq&=C
\end{align}$

"OP" had made a typo in the last equality which needed  a sign change:

So, now the above simultaneous equations are satisfied by:

$(A,B,C)=(4,3,5)$ & $(p,q,r)=(7,4,8)$

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tagging your post with "diophantine equations",
it is to assume that we are dealing with integers.

We have that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  Ax = By \hfill \cr 
  \gcd (x,y) = 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  A = ny \hfill \cr 
  B = nx \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Then it is clear how to proceed if $gcd(x,y) \ne 1$.